# My countdown doesnt start on my betting site

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, steam

I have a csgo betting site, when atleast 2 players deposit their skins into the site it the game starts and it takes 2 minutes until the the bot picks a winner.

Everything works fine, the game starts, a winner is picked 2 minutes after the game started, but the countdown text that are supposed to display the seconds left is not working.

this is my code `Time left: <h4 id="countdown-timer"><span id="timeleft">0</span></h4>`

> Accepted trade offer #1211760373 by XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
>   Current Players: 1
>   Accepted trade offer #1211760308 by XXXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
>   Current Players: 2
>   Found 2 Players

and that is what  the bot says

and this is the timeleft.php http://prnt.sc/b03ute

PHP Code

```
<?php
@include_once ("set.php");
$game = fetchinfo("value", "info", "name", "current_game");
$r = fetchinfo("starttime", "games", "id", $game);
$somebodywon = fetchinfo("winner", "games", "id", $game);
if ($r == 2147483647)
    die("120");
$r += 120 - time();
if ($r < 0) {
    $r = 0; /* if(empty($somebodywon)) include_once('getwinner34634f.php'); */
} echo $r;
?>
```

Found this one aswell, called ssetimeleft.php

```
<

?php
@include_once ("set.php");
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of event data.

/**
 * Constructs the SSE data format and flushes that data to the client.
 *
 * @param string $id Timestamp/id of this connection.
 * @param string $msg Line of text that should be transmitted.
 */
function sendMsg($id, $msg) {
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
while (1) {
    $game = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");
    $r = fetchinfo("starttime","games","id",$game);
    if($r == 2147483647){
        $var=120;
    }else{
        $var = $r += 120-time();
        if($r < 0)
        {
            $var = 0;
            /*if(empty($somebodywon))
                include_once('getwinner34634f.php');*/
        }
    }
    sendMsg(time(),$var);
    usleep(500000); //1000000 = 1 seconds

}
?>
```

Comment: Please provide the code that is supposed to update the time display text. (Probably javascript?)

Comment: Please update your question with this code, so that it's more readable.

Comment: i just did, do you know how to help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see what you are trying to do here without more information but the `time()` function in your PHP file runs only when the server-side PHP processor processes this file. The countdown display, however, is something that should be handled client side.

I recommend adding a javascript or jQuery file to handle the countdown display for you.

Comment: I dont know how to make a code like that from scratch, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this its a very basic example :

```js
$(function() {
  var time_out = 10;
  var timeout = setInterval(calculate, 1000);

  function calculate() {
    $('#timeleft').text(time_out--);
    if (time_out < 0) {
      clearInterval(timeout);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h4 id="countdown-timer"><span id="timeleft">0</span></h4>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.